# How do you change the text of a span from silverlight, or is this a bug?

Tags: c#, silverlight, esri

I am developing a silverlight application using the ESRI Gis map.  I have it setup to when I move a marker around, it changes the Longitude,Latitude of the marker and I update a label.  I am using this code:

```
        HtmlElement eleLbl = doc.GetElementById("lblGISLocation");
        if (eleLbl != null)
        {
            eleLbl.SetAttribute("innerHTML", latlng.X.ToString() + "," + latlng.Y.ToString());
        }
```

This works fine on a PC in all browsers.  This is the result I get from Firefox on a PC:

```
<span id="lblGISLocation">-122.304918344379,47.3867897587541</span>
```

But the same code running on a Mac using either Firefox, Safari or Chrome gives this result:

```
<span innerhtml="-122.288384409929,47.3832784255738" id="lblGISLocation">0,0</span>
```

Any Ideas on how I can make this work in either machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SetProperty method of the HtmlElement:

```
HtmlElement eleLbl = doc.GetElementById("lblGISLocation");
if (eleLbl != null)
{
    eleLbl.SetProperty("innerHTML", latlng.X.ToString() + "," + latlng.Y.ToString());
}
```

Comment: There is no InnerHTML property or method on an HtmlElement object.

Comment: @BitcoSoftware you are right... I was confused with another kind of HtmlElement. I edited my answer.